# How can I wrap function with parameters into wrapper with parameters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipeline, wrapper

UPDATE V2:
Allright, I've written some code in my free time and came up with this idea. It works, but I don't know why. What is the difference between these codes that makes it actually work?

class Base:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.prevention = [
        'targetDeceleration',
        'collisionPrevention',
        ]
    self.correct = []
    self.incorrect = []

def mapping(self, signal: list, data: list or np.ndarray, idx_list: list, filename: str, support: list = None):
    def outer_wrapper(func):
        def inner_wrapper(*args):
            for idx, sig in enumerate(signal):
                print(sig)
                if support:
                    print(support[idx])
                for idx_triplet in idx_list:
                    eth_idx, spi_idx, _ = idx_triplet
                    is_correct = func(sig, eth_idx, spi_idx, support)
                    if is_correct:
                        print('Correct')
                        self.correct.append(sig)
                    else:
                        print('Incorrect')
                        self.incorrect.append(sig)
                    print(filename)
        return inner_wrapper
    return outer_wrapper 

@abstractmethod
def mapping_check(self):
    pass
```

class AEB(Base):

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

def mapping_check(self):
    data = np.full((4,), 5)
    idx_list = [
        [1, 1, 1]
    ]
    fname = 'FILENAME'
    
    @Base.mapping(
        self,
        signal=self.prevention,
        data=data,
        idx_list=idx_list,
        filename=fname,
        support=['idTarget', 'syncId']
    )
    def prevention_mapping(self, sig: list, eth_idx: int, spi_idx: int) -> bool:
        return eth_idx == spi_idx
    
    prevention_mapping()
```

UPDATE:

```
@Functionality.mapping_functionality
    def id_target_object_fcm_mapping(eth_signal, spi_idx, eth_idx) -> bool:
        # FCF_VD_KEYS from A to E
        idx_A = FCF_VD_KEYS.index('A')
        idx_E = FCF_VD_KEYS.index('E')
        fcf_vd_keys = FCF_VD_KEYS[idx_A: idx_E + 1]
        # Check ETH and SPI mapping
        for key in fcf_vd_keys:
            # Check SPI mapping
            PDD_469_1_1 = FCF_VD_IDS['FCV'][spi_idx] == FCF_VD_IDS[key][spi_idx]
            PDD_469_1_2 = FCF_VD_ALERTS[key][spi_idx] == 43605
            PDD_469_1 = PDD_469_1_1 and PDD_469_1_2
            if PDD_469_1:
                # Check for appropriate idTargetObjectFCMCam values
                PDD_469_2 = eth_signal[eth_idx] == FCF_VD_IDS[key][spi_idx]
                if PDD_469_2:
                    return True

        # Check for default value
        IS_DEFAULT = eth_signal[eth_idx] == 0
        if IS_DEFAULT:
            return True
        # Otherwise return incorrect mapping
        return False


    def mapping_functionality(self):
    def inner_wrapper(function, eth_signal, pickle_data, idx_list, file_name, support_signal=None):
        print('inner wrapper')
        for idx, sig in enumerate(eth_signal):
            # Get ETH signal to be mapped
            eth_signal = Functionality.get_eth_signal(sig, pickle_data)
            # Load support signal
            if support_signal:
                support_signal = Functionality.get_eth_signal(support_signal[idx], pickle_data)
            for spi_idx, eth_idx, _ in idx_list:
                # Boolean storing info whether ETH was mapped correctly to the SPI signal
                # Update output
                is_mapping_correct = function(eth_signal, spi_idx, eth_idx, support_signal)
                if is_mapping_correct:
                    if self.result[sig] != self.incorrect:
                        self.result[sig] = self.correct
                else:
                    self.result[sig] = self.incorrect
                    if sig not in self.corrupted_files[file_name]:
                        self.corrupted_files[file_name][sig] = []
                    self.corrupted_files[file_name][sig].append([spi_idx, eth_idx])
    return inner_wrapper
```

Unfortunately, after trying to run the code:

```
id_target_object_fcm_mapping(self.id_target_object_fcm_sig, pickle_data, idx_list, file_name)
```

I get the error, that mapping_functionality() misses the file_name parameter. How can I fix that?

so basically I want to wrap this function:

```
@Functionality.mapping_functionality(
        self=self,
        eth_signal=self.id_target_object_fcm_sig,
        pickle_data=pickle_data,
        idx_list=idx_list,
        file_name=file_name,
    )
    def id_target_object_fcm_mapping(eth_signal, spi_idx, eth_idx, *args) -> bool:
        # FCF_VD_KEYS from A to E
        idx_A = FCF_VD_KEYS.index('A')
        idx_E = FCF_VD_KEYS.index('E')
        fcf_vd_keys = FCF_VD_KEYS[idx_A: idx_E + 1]

        # Check ETH and SPI mapping
        for key in fcf_vd_keys:
            # Check SPI mapping
            PDD_469_1_1 = FCF_VD_IDS['FCV'][spi_idx] == FCF_VD_IDS[key][spi_idx]
            PDD_469_1_2 = FCF_VD_ALERTS[key][spi_idx] == 43605
            PDD_469_1 = PDD_469_1_1 and PDD_469_1_2
            if PDD_469_1:
                # Check for appropriate idTargetObjectFCMCam values
                PDD_469_2 = eth_signal[eth_idx] == FCF_VD_IDS[key][spi_idx]
                if PDD_469_2:
                    return True

        # Check for default value
        IS_DEFAULT = eth_signal[eth_idx] == 0
        if IS_DEFAULT:
            return True
        # Otherwise return incorrect mapping
        return False
```

Into a function that will iterate through indices and update the spreadsheet depending on the boolean from wrapped function:

```
    def mapping_functionality(self, eth_signal, pickle_data, idx_list, file_name, support_signal=None):
    for idx, sig in enumerate(eth_signal):
        # Get ETH signal to be mapped
        eth_signal = Functionality.get_eth_signal(sig, pickle_data)

        # Load support signal
        if support_signal:
            support_signal = Functionality.get_eth_signal(support_signal[idx], pickle_data)

        def outer_wrapper(function):
            # Iterate over signal indices
            for spi_idx, eth_idx, _ in idx_list:
                # Boolean storing info whether ETH was mapped correctly to the SPI signal
                @wraps(function)
                def inner_wrapper():
                    is_mapping_correct = function(eth_signal, spi_idx, eth_idx, support_signal)
                    # Update output
                    if is_mapping_correct:
                        if self.result[sig] != self.incorrect:
                            self.result[sig] = self.correct
                    else:
                        self.result[sig] = self.incorrect
                        if sig not in self.corrupted_files[file_name]:
                            self.corrupted_files[file_name][sig] = []
                        self.corrupted_files[file_name][sig].append([spi_idx, eth_idx])
                    return inner_wrapper
        return outer_wrapper
```

Unfortunately after trying to call the function:

```
id_target_object_fcm_mapping()
```

I get the following Error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

How can I fix that issue?

Comment: Your `outer_wrapper` doesn't return anything.

Comment: @L3viathan how can I change the code so it will return the correct thing?

Answer (score 1):

Its difficult to understand if the behaviour of your code would be as expected with fixes since you have not provided information around the class objects and what you are trying to do.

Usually, it's better to simplify the problem and provide it as a reproducible example on SO.

Assuming your underlying question is what the title suggests,

> How can I wrap function with parameters into wrapper with parameters?

Here is the general structure of passing parameters via decorators is as follows. Hope this helps -

```
def decorator_function(n):
    def outer_wrapper(f):
        def inner_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            out = f(*args, **kwargs)**n
            return out
        return inner_wrapper
    return outer_wrapper

@decorator_function(4)        #<- Decorator with argument
def function(x, m):
    return x/m

print(function(10,3))
print((10/3)**4)
```

```
123.45679012345681
123.45679012345681
```

The original function takes in `x` divides it by `m`. The wrapper takes in `n` and applies it as a power on the output of the original function, so, `(x/m)^n`

---

**EDIT:** Just to add the lambda function method of creating nested decorator functions, because I personally find them more readable (weird right?)

```
decorator = lambda n:lambda f:lambda *args, **kwargs: f(*args, **kwargs)**n

@decorator(4)
def function(x, m):
    return x/m

function(10,3)
```

```
123.45679012345681
```

You can easily see whats happening here -

```
   lambda n:lambda f:lambda *args, **kwargs: f(*args, **kwargs)**n
#  |                 |                       |________________|  | |
#  |                 |                        original function  | |
#  |                 |___________________________________________| |
#  |                  wrapper takes in f and returns inner lambda  |
#  |_______________________________________________________________|
#       outer function takes n parameter and returns wrapper
```

Comment: But this template does not include parameters in the function that is used to wrap. That's my main problem.

Comment: It does, n is that parameter, `wrapper(m, *args, **kwargs)`. You can add more as you like.

Comment: You cant add the parameters while decorating with `@decorator_function`. You have to pass those params during function call.

Comment: Check the example where instead of passing just `x`, `m` to the original function I pass `n`, `x` and `m`, which are required by the wrapper. While decorating I only use `@decorator_function` and not `@decorator_function(n)`

Comment: Can you post it in your question itself (just edit and add it under your original question text), its hard to read it in the comments. thanks!

Comment: Hi, can you roll back to your original question? I read throught the question and updated my answer which should be more inline to what you were trying to do.

Comment: Reverted and Updated ;)

Comment: You are returning the `inner_wrapper` in the `inner_wrapper()` function itself. Is that a typo or a bug which you may want to correct?

Comment: It is a typo. But i see the problem. mapping_functionality takes eth_signal, pickle_data, idx_list, file_name, support_signal=None as parameters, while id_target_object_fcm_mapping takes eth_signal, spi_idx, eth_idx as parameters. eth_signal is the same and i need to put it directly to the wrapped function. Spi_idx and Eth_idx are obtained from idx_list, and they need to be pasted to the wrapped function as well. The problem is, I cannot use the same arguments that were passed to the mapping_functionality while i am calling the wrapped function inside...

Comment: Maybe i understand it wrong, but are you trying to use a parameter that is available in an inner function, in an outer function?